# Create Trigger : update table column by inserting data into another table rows

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

Please Help me to create triggers,
I have 2 tables of

```
data
+---------+------------+-------+-------+
| id | info_id | rate  | qty   | total |
+----+---------+------------+----------+
| 80 |    10   | 150   |   5   |  750  |
+----+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| 81 |    10   | 50    |   5   |  250  |
+--------------+-------+-------+-------+

info
+---------+---------------+------------+
| id  |  name  |  gtotal  |  dated     |
+-----+--------+----------+------------+
| 10  |  Hari  |     NULL | 2021-05-15 |
+---------+------------+---------------+
```

I want to create a trigger through phpmyadmin, as soon as data will be inserted, then `info.gtotal` will be updated by adding `data.total` from matched `info_id` from table name- data.

what will be the trigger if update on data happens too. I just want to create both triggers.

I am new with such, please help me. Any help is accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create two triggers one for insert and another for update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_trigger`
AFTER INSERT ON `data`
FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE info
SET gtotal = gtotal + new.total
WHERE id = new.info_id;
```

> Here new.info_id will have the info_id value of newly insert record

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_trigger`
AFTER UPDATE ON `data`
FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE info
SET gtotal = (gtotal - old.total) + new.total
WHERE id = new.info_id;
```

> Here old.total will have the total value of record before updating. new.total is the total value after updation.

Since you haven't conveyed what to do after update I have added the logic of subtracting the total from old total and added the new total value. Change it as per your requirement.

You can also create these triggers using **GUI** in phpmyadmin. You have to select the triggers in the menu bar and add the trigger definition.

[image: PhpMyAdminTrigger]

Comment: Thank You so much for your detailed reply. I loved it. firstly it is not worked but as soon I simply added `new.total` which worked. Final code became to
 `UPDATE info
SET gtotal = gtotal + new.total
WHERE id = new.info_id;` Which worked.